# What's the easiest way to stop a function from being called every X seconds in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've looked around for a soundproof solution to my problem but was not able to find many SO questions like this.

My `move` function gets called each click on a tile, I want to block the user from moving whilst they are currently in motion to block overlapping execution bugs.

The functions work as following:

```js
move: function(steps){
    for (var stepx in steps) {
      window.setTimeout(. . ., 300 * stepx);
    }
}
```

Which iterates, adding a forward 300ms to when the function is going to be called each time. If it's **5 steps**, it'll finish after **1.5 seconds**.

But, when the user clicks twice it sets up a parallel bunch of handlers that glitch the user from two areas: the original path being travelled and the secondary.

Is there a way to block execution or queue the timeouts?

Comment: Try reading about `clearTimeout` or about debouncing and throttling techniques
 https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function

Comment: Add the moves to a queue and dequeue them one at a time

Comment: Add a 'moving' flag and don't add new moves/steps if already moving

Comment: @freedomn-m just did this and it worked thanks, but the question still does stand to be able to block the function for X seconds. :~)

Comment: block the function by not adding moves when moving is true - I mean, if you did it and it worked, then you've just done what you set out to do - which is your preferred solution, block or queue?

Comment: block a function *for* X seconds is different from blocking a function from being called

Comment: Thanks for the help, if someone wants to write up an answer go ahead - I'll be closing the question in 10 minutes.

Comment: Move `steps` to an outer scope and your `move: function(steps)` just append to the outer array, with a separate function to execute them - if already running just keep running, if not, start running

Comment: `I'll be closing the question in 10` - why would anyone want to write an answer to a question you are closing?

Comment: TBH: There are too many options to make this a useful question beyond your immediate need.  And, because there are many options, it becomes opinion based (so liable to close-voting)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to save the timeout to a variable and call `clearTimeout()` - however, your example creates multiple timeouts in a loop, so you'd need to save them all and then stop them all.  It could be done like this:

```js
var timers = [];
var running = false;

function makeSteps(steps) {
  if (!running) {
    running = true;
    for (var i = 0; i <= steps; i++) {
      timers.push(setTimeout(function() {
        console.log("Step");
      }, 300 * i));
    }
  }
}

function stopAllSteps() {
  for (var i = 0; i <= timers.length; i++) {
    clearTimeout(timers[i]);
  }
  running = false;
  console.log("stopped!");
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="makeSteps(100)">Start</button>
<button type="button" onclick="stopAllSteps()">Stop</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use of a variable to block the user clicks until it gets done.

If I understood well what you asked for.

```js
let inProgress = false;

function clickFunc(steps) {
  console.log('The user clicked');

  if (inProgress) {
    console.log('Action already in progress');

    return;
  }

  inProgress = true;

  for (let i = 0; i < steps; i += 1) {
    window.setTimeout(() => {
      // if the last step is over, we stop the click block
      if (i === steps - 1) {
        inProgress = false;
      }

      console.log('One step done');
    }, 300 * i);
  }
}
```

```css
.button {
  height: 2em;
  width: 10em;
  background-color: #444444;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.button:hover {
  opacity: 0.9;
}
```

```html
<div class="button" onclick="clickFunc(3)">Button</div>
```